# good country to live in vs live

Tags: prepositions

*I think here is not the worst possible place to live, but there are many other countries that seem to be better to live*

"in" after the first "live" seems optional. But the preposition seems lacking after the second one.

Can you illuminate me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the lack of the word 'place' that makes the second instance sound wrong without the preposition.

Consider:

- That restaurant is *a great place to eat*.
- That restaurant is great to eat.

If you think about it, either of these could sound like you want to eat the restaurant itself, rather than the food they serve. But when a phrase is idiomatic, we get the meaning and there is no ambiguity. The latter, not being idiomatic, has that problem, so you'd add that it is *great to eat **in***.